# how to look for help on a command output

Tags: man, info

If I search for man pages for a command I only see the information on the parameters that I can pass to the command.
How do I find details on the command output? for example what each column of the output means.
For example ps cmd by default produces output with following column heads- 
PID, TTY, TIME and CMD.
If I need to find information on what the TIME column is how do I find in the man page of ps command.

Comment: Please read the full text of the manpage. I confirmed that the answer you seek is in there on at least two modern UNIX-like operating systems: RHEL and Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page I have for command ps does explain what the columns
mean. A good start is to search "OUTPUT"
(<kbd>/</kbd>OUTPUT<kbd>Enter</kbd>) if you want to find the sections
that have this word in their name, or look for, e.g., "TIME" to find
this:

```
CODE        HEADER    DESCRIPTION
(...)
cputime     TIME      cumulative CPU time, "[DD-]hh:mm:ss" format.
                      (alias time).
```

Answer (score 0):

You `man ps' page should have the information you need.

The best way is to search for a word, say `TIME`, is from within the man page, using one of the two internal search commands:

`/TIME` will search in the forward direction for the first instance of `TIME`. You can then navigate to the next instance of `TIME` by simply pressing `n`. You can navigate to the previous instance of `TIME` by pressing `N`.

`?TIME` works the same way except that it start searching at the end of the man page, and will find the last instance of the word `TIME`. You can then navigate through the instances of the word `TIME` using `N` and `n` as stated above.

Note that you can find this information while viewing the man page at any time by typing `h` for help. Typing `q` will then return you to the man page.